# Submit function in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to call jquery Submit() function in while submitting the form in html. Below is my code but the respective function will not work.
Can any one please  help me out regarding this.

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" onsubmit="return Submit();">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jquery, then you'll want to bind the click event to your button.

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" id="submit_form_button">

<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){  
           $( "#submit_form_button" ).click(function() {
             //function here

           });


     });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onsubmit` is a `<form>` attribute.

```js
function Submit(){
    alert ("I Worked!")
    return false; // just to stop the submitting of the form.
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return Submit();">
     <input type="submit" value="Register" >
</form>
```

Comment: @swamy was this helpful?